# What is the best way to check if a given userprofile is active or deleted in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, user-profile

I have a list of usernames. In C++ which way would it be better to check if the profile associated with the username exists  or deleted in the local machine? I came across ATL CAccessToken class methods and Win32 APIs with GetTokenInformation etc. Which one would be better on performance perspective too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that performance-wise a single call to gather the entire list of all users would be faster than verifying them individually.  You can do that using the `NetUserEnum` function as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This will also get you the status flags so you know if the user account has been disabled, locked out, their password expired, etc.

Comment: Great :-) This is the one I am exactly looking for.